# Showing that a constructed point is the circumcenter of a given triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference (exact copy of the question):

> In the figure shown, what notable dot is "$E$" for triangle $ABC$? (answer: circumcenter)

Original figure:
[image]

> [image]

My progress: The original figure does not make it clear whether the centers of the circles are coincident or whether points $A$ and $C$ are tangent to the smaller circle.
So I made this figure that seems to me to be the correct one.
Based on it I can say with certainty that:

$\angle E=90^\circ\\ EA=EC \therefore \triangle EAC(\text{isosceles})\implies \angle C=\angle A = 45^o$

So, $AE$ isn't a angle bisector and therefore $E$ isn't incenter

$AE$ is not perpendicular to $BC$ therefore $E$ is not orthocenter

The prolongation of $AE$ is not midpoint of $BC$ so $E$ is not barycenter

Need to show that $EA=EB$...

Comment: Can you add original figure?

Comment: @ACB..no problems...I've already posted...

Comment: another way to demonstrate would be to prove that $\angle ABC = \frac{\angle AEC}{2}$

Comment: Excellent ..great demonstration ..thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\small \angle EAC=\angle AOC=\angle ECA=\angle CJA=45^\circ$ (alternate segment theorem)

Also $\small \angle BAC=\angle CJO$ and $\small \angle BCA=\angle AOJ$. (exterior angles of cyclic quadrilateral $\small AOJC$)

Say $\small \angle AJO=\alpha$ and $\small \angle COJ=\beta$. Thus $\small \angle BAE=\alpha$ and $\small \angle BCE=\beta$.

Considering $\small \triangle AOJ$, $\small \alpha+\beta+45^\circ=90^\circ\implies\alpha+\beta=45^\circ$

Considering $\small \triangle ABC$, $\small \alpha+\beta+45^\circ+45^\circ+\angle ABC=180^\circ$ $\small \implies\angle ABC=45^\circ$

Already found $\small \angle AEC=90^\circ$, $\small \angle ABC=\frac12 \angle AEC$. Also $\small AE=EC$. Therefore $\small E$ is the circumcentre of $\small \triangle ABC$.

Comment: From what I can tell, all the angle-chasing still works to give $\angle E=2(\alpha+\beta)=2\angle B$, without having to assume $\angle E$ is a right angle. That is, $M$, $N$, and $\bigcirc EMN$ appear to be irrelevant. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, @Blue , there's no need of the outer circle. Also no need for $\angle E$ to be $90^\circ$.